# Image not loading after moving art.scnassets folder

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, xcode9, arkit

After creating a new "Augment Reality App" project in Xcode, I want to move `art.scnassets` folder from its default location to `/Resources/` folder that I created. So the folder path would be like `Resources/art.scnassets`. However, it fails to load a png file in it if I move the folder. See below:

Before (working):

```
// art.scnassets folder is in its default place
// below code loads image.png
print(UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/image.png")!)
```

After (not working):

```
// moved folder to "Resources/art.scnassets"
// Resources folder is a group.
// below returns `nil`
print(UIImage(named: "Resources/art.scnassets/image.png")!)
```

I cleaned up the builds, and checked `Copy Bundle Resources` menu as well, but there is nothing wrong. If I move `art.scnassets` folder back to the project root, it works, meaning code works fine.

What should I do to move `art.scnassets` to somewhere else? I am new to Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using the first code?

```
print(UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/image.png")!)
```

As far as I know it doesn't matter in which folder the scnassets are, you can refer to it the same way.